# Meteor JS, pass json data as params to HTTP.call

Tags: ajax, meteor

I need to pass a json as params to HTTP.call.

My code is:

```
HTTP.call("POST", "URL_TO_MY_WS", {
    params: {
        "IdLavanderia": "304BEACD-9B9C-42B7-B90B-83D563A9C8FE",
        "DettaglioListino": [{
            "IdListino": "",
            "NomeProdotto": "Gonna",
            "DescrizioneBreveProdotto": "Gonna in pelle",
            "DescrizioneLungaProdotto": "Gonna in pelle",
            "CodiceProdottoListino": "GON002",
            "PrezzoLisitno": "1",
            "PercentualeSconto": "0",
            "Prezzo": "1",
            "AttivoAl": "",
            "AttivoDal": "",
            "DettaglioListino": [{
                "Quantita": 1,
                "IdProdotto": "fd97afce-6968-48de-9f86-21e1ada350dc"
            }]
        }]
    },
    headers: {
        'Authorization': "MY_ACCESS_TOKEN",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
    }
}, function(error, result) {
    if (!error) {
        console.log(result)
    }
});
```

But using command "meteor debug" i see that params are passed as query string array.
Network tab show this:

```
IdLavanderia=304BEACD-9B9C-42B7-B90B-83D563A9C8FE&DettaglioListino[]%5BIdListino%5D=&DettaglioListino[]%5BNomeProdotto%5D=Gonna&DettaglioListino[]%5BDescrizioneBreveProdotto%5D=Gonna......
```

How can i force to pass in json format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/http.html#HTTP-call), you just have to place your object in `data` field, rather than in `params` field.

Comment: Don't worry, that happens with all of us :)